# Running migrations on already existing database fails if column that is used by stored procedure renamed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dbup

Some time ago I created a database. For simplicity lets assume that I created single table and stored procedure in that db. To create database, table and procedures I use DbUp. SQL scripts that I have written:

001_CREATE_TABLE_dbo.TestTable.sql

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables where object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.TestTable', N'U'))
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable (
        Id bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        ColumnToRename nvarchar(128) NULL
    );
END;
```

002_CREATE_SP_dbo.TestSP.sql

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.TestSP
    @Id bigint
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.TestTable
    WHERE Id = @Id AND ColumnToRename IS NOT NULL;
END;
```

Then I used these table and proc, insert data, etc. Later I realized that I need to rename column `ColumnToRename` in TestTable. I created another two scripts to achieve this: first rename column, then alter procedure.

003_dbo.TestTable_RENAME_ColumnToRename_TO_RenamedColumn.sql

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns 
          WHERE Name = N'ColumnToRename'
          AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'dbo.TestTable'))
BEGIN
   EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.TestTable.ColumnToRename', 'RenamedColumn', 'COLUMN';
END
```

004_ALTER_SP_dbo.TestSP.sql

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.TestSP
    @Id bigint
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.TestTable
    WHERE Id = @Id AND RenamedColumn IS NOT NULL;
END;
```

But when I run DbUp with this scripts SQL Server throws error when run 002_CREATE_SP_dbo.TestSP.sql saying that column with name `ColumnToRename` does not exists.

Program.cs

```
var upgrader =
    DeployChanges.To
        .SqlDatabase(connectionString)
        .WithScriptsFromFileSystem(scriptsPath)
        .WithVariables(variables)
        .LogScriptOutput()
        .LogToConsole()
        .Build();

var result = upgrader.PerformUpgrade();
```

How can I say to DbUp that it should not run first two script and run only last two one? Or how can I write second script in such a way that it creates proc only on first run?

Comment: Just drop the sp first. and run the rename table script . the create sp with renamed column.

Comment: When running dbup your should have a history type table which knows what has been run, is that correct? so if you run the first two and then run the second 2 it wont run the first 2 as they will be listed in the history type table called SchemaVersion.

Comment: You may also want to start writing all your scripts in sp_executesql N'...'; blocks as then it wont be able to check columns until it runs them. This is something we have done in many of our SQL migration tools. This does mean its all a big string where you have to escape single quotes with two single quotes or more; but honestly it worked well.